# Can "liegen" be used for people?

Tags: word-usage, verb

Can "*liegen*" be used for people. For instance

> *I am here.* - *Ich liege hier.*

or it is wrong?

Is *Ich bin hier* better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ich liege hier* means something different than *Ich bin hier*, so the answer is **no**

Usage examples:

> *liegen*: *Ich liege im Bett.* -> you're literally lying in bed
>   *sein*: *Ich bin in Berlin.* -> you're located in Berlin

***Exceptions:***

- *Berlin liegt in Deutschland* is correct
- *Die Banane liegt im Kühlschrank* is also correct

→ Basically, you can say it's incorrect if it's related to a creature (animal/person/...).

Comment: can you add another example ?

Comment: can i ask what you dont understand? because basically it's that, that you have to notice that `liegen` means `lying` and is not the same like `ich bin hier` -> `i am here`

Comment: added a "rule" for it and exception-example

Comment: Unless you refer to geographical entities, "liegen" always indicates a (mostly) horizontal orientation. "Die Flasche liegt im Kühlschrank" may be correct, provided that the bottle is lying; if it's standing upright, it must be "... steht im Kühlschrank". "Der Fernseher liegt im Wohnzimmer" is certainly incorrect, and "Das Brandenburger Tor liegt in Berlin" also sounds a bit strange. I don't think that there is a general distinction between animate and inanimate beings in connection with "liegen"

Comment: i dont agree with you entirely. Sentence like "Das Brandenburger Tor liegt in Berlin" you hear often and i would say its correct, because you mean the geographic location. Also in this sentence the "Brandenburger Tor" is on a horizontal orientation, but you dont actually mean lying. For the sentence with the television i agree, that sounds weird and here you really mean he's lying on the ground. In summary i guess you can also say, in addition to creatures, also "easy" movable objects indicate that you mean literally lying with `liegen`

Comment: "Kalkutta liegt am Ganges, Berlin liegt an der Spree; und dass ich so verliebt bin, das liegt an Marlene" -- sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: Teylyn says it all :)